# Find out the player's password on the Minecraft server

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I am the owner of a Minecraft server, and I would like to find out the passwords of the players, because I would like to shoot a video on YouTube "I log in to subscribers' accounts"

I haven't tried anything

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not possible. That would be a huge security issue